# Play!/Morphia - Return MongoID as string (within json) / blobFieldsTracker Field

Tags: java, playframework, mongoid

I'am relatively new to java and want to try out something new. At the moment I'am trying out the java framework play.

What I'am trying to do is to rewrite a little REST JSON Api written in php as a play rest service.

I'am using mongodb as datastore and therefore I installed morphia. Everything is working as expected. But I'am a little bit confused about the json result renderJSON() produces.

Here is the code of my model:

```
@AutoTimestamp
@Entity
public class Bookmark extends Model {
public String title;
public String url;
public String description;
public List tags;
public boolean is_private;

public Bookmark(String title,
                String url,
                String description,
                String tags,
                boolean is_private)
{
    this.title          = title;
    this.url            = url;
    this.description    = description;
    this.tags           = Arrays.asList(tags.split(" "));
    this.is_private     = is_private;
}
 }
```

To retrieve all bookmarks I'am using the following method within the controller:

```
    public static void listAll() {
        List<Bookmark> bookmarks = Bookmark.findAll();
        renderJSON(bookmarks);
    }
```

Here is a line of the result:

```
[{"title":"Test","url":"http://www.google.de","description":"test","tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag5","tag0209135913598"],"is_private":true,"_id":{"_time":1331202670,"_machine":-637116226,"_inc":989037616,"_new":false},"_created":1331202670469,"_modified":1331202670469,"blobFieldsTracker":{}}]
```

I'am a little bit confused now about the "_id"-Object with the attributes "_time", "_machine" and so on. And I'am also confused about "blobFieldsTracker".

For the attribute "_id" I would expect a mongoid. I could not find anything related to that within the docs or with google so my question is what I have to do to include the "real" mongoid within the json-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following render statement:

`renderJSON(bookmarks, new play.modules.morphia.utils.ObjectIdGsonAdapter());`

About the `blobFieldsTracker`, it's a housekeeping field morphia plugin enhanced to your model class. For now, just ignore it in your javascript.

Comment: In the latest version you can use String type ID: http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia-1.2.8-RC1/model#id